# Uncaught (in promise) NotSupportedError: The element has no supported sources. Playing Audio On Page Click Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension

I've been trying for 4 hours to make a simple Chrome extension that plays a sound when I click somewhere on any web page but I keep getting errors, the most recent being "Uncaught (in promise) NotSupportedError: The element has no supported sources".

```
popup.js
```

var x= new Audio();
x.src="shot2.mp3";

```
    window.addEventListener("click",function(){
    var x= document.getElementById('fire');
    document.body.addEventListener('click',window.onclick);
},false);
    window.onclick=function playAudio(){
        x.play();
    }
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Firepower Browsing</title>

    <script src="popup.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>test</h1>



</body>
</html>
```

manifest.json

```
    {
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Firepower Browsing",
  "description": "Add a little firepower to your browsing with this explosive extension!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [
      "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "js": ["popup.js"]
  }
],"browser_action": {}
,"background": {
    "scripts": ["popup.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
 "content_security_policy": "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'self'; object-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'",
  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab"
   ]
}
```

Comment: Where is `shot2.mp3`? If it is part of your extension and your script is a content script then you need a [proper path](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getURL) and [permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) to access that file

Comment: Do `window.onclick=function(){
        x.play();
    }'